# WordPress Function Ignoring CSS

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation

I am having trouble getting this function to display properly:

```
function time_box() {
    echo '<div class="desktop-time" title="'.the_time( 'j F Y' ).'"><div class="month">'.the_time( 'M' ).'</div><div class="day">'.the_time( 'd' ).'</div></div>';
}
```

The issue is that, although it does show the time and date, it seems to ignore the css and such. I.E. it shows the time were the .desktop-time class is originally at. For reference, the desktop-time is a div that is positioned absolutely and moved ~200 pixels left. The function above puts the time at its original position. Additionally this is placed inside the WordPress functions.php

I have called the function in the home.php file with

```
<?php the_time(); ?>
```

CSS:

```
.desktop-time {
    border: 5px solid #d0d0d0;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 25px 0 0 -100px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}

.desktop-time .month {
    background: url("vertical-background.png");
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.desktop-time .day {
    background: #a52a2a;
    font-size: 35px;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://imageshack.com/a/img903/7499/M5NsGw.png

Comment: Can you post the CSS and link you are working with?

Comment: Edited the original, main issue is the_time() ignore the css. The desktop-time box displays properly, however, the text generated from the_time() displays at the boxes original position before the css move.

Comment: Can you create a demo of your problem? Anything you are working live or in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Added an image for reference.

Comment: This has to be a very simple solution that I can analyse by looking at the code directly. With current code, nothing much can be said about it. What if it is affected by other elements for the movement. What is the URL of the site you just gave a screenshot for?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I actually finally figured it out. Apparently switching all of the dots to commas fixed the issue with the CSS. Thanks!